# Do email sent from php mailer counts?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

If my server allows 200 email/hour and i send email using php mailer. Do server counts mail sent from php mailer or not.

Actually my client some time sends more than 200 email per hour using outlook.
And web page sends email to users using php mailer. Some time users are not receiving any email from website not in any folder.Is it due to exceeding email per hour?
I made it 500 email per hour but finds same problem some time. I just wanna know do hosting provider/server counts email sent from php mailer?
Ignore smtp here.

Comment: Ask your hosting provider. The answer will depend entirely on how they implement these limits.

Answer (score 1):

No Php mailer never counts emails sent from mailer. Actually mail server of hosting provider would count the mails.

You can check with your hosting provider for mail failure. It can be in mail queue or some other smtp issue.